# SQL query where count is >= 3

Tags: sql

I'm new with SQL, and am trying to execute a query that would only return each Category if each one appears 4 times or more. From googling, it seems like I should be using having count, but it doesn't seem return the categories.

Any ideas?

```
SELECT Category
FROM myTable
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3";
```

Comment: Add `Group By Category` to your query. And also specify which dbms you are using.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query that will "return each Category if each one appears 4 times or more."

```
SELECT Category
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Category
HAVING count(*) >= 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your query like this by adding the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT Category
FROM myTable
group by category
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4;  -- Change this to 4 to return each Category if each one appears 4 times or more
```

Answer (score 0):

The `HAVING` clause only works in conjunction with `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT Category
FROM myTable
GROUP BY CATEGORY
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3;
```

Also changed your `HAVING` based on your post of wanting to know 4 or more.